# displaying specific records of a uses

Tags: php, mysql, html

guys please check my codes in displaying record..

```
<?php

include("db.php"); 
$username=$_POST['username']; 
$email=$_POST['email'];

$query="SELECT * FROM members where username = '$username'";

$result=mysql_query($query); 
$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();


?> <br /> <p></p>

Welcome back! Your details below: <br /><br /> 

<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5"> 
<tr> 
 <th>First Name</th> 
 <th>Last Name</th>
 <th>User Name</th>
 <th>Email</th> 
 <th>Age</th> 
</tr>

<?

$i = 0;

while ($i < $num) {

$firstname=mysql_result($result, $i, 'firstname'); 
$lastname=mysql_result($result, $i, 'lastname'); 
$username=mysql_result($result, $i, 'username'); 
$email=mysql_result($result, $i, 'email'); 
$age= mysql_result($result, $i, 'age');

?>

 <tr> 
   <td><? echo $firstname ?></td> 
   <td><? echo $lastname ?></td>
   <td><? echo $username ?></td>
   <td><? echo $email ?></td>
   <td><? echo $age ?></td>
 </tr>

<?

$i++;

}

echo "</table>"; ?>
```

is it correct?

:-(

Comment: ... What are we supposed to be looking for? You've not provided any errors or issues.

Comment: Make sure you cleanse and escape $username before inserting it into your SQL statement

Comment: http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: It's starting to get boring, but: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing fatally wrong with your code but there's a few very basic alterations i would make:

```
<?php

include "db.php"; 
$username=$_POST['username']; 
$email=$_POST['email'];

// added mysql_real_escape_string to prevent sql injection
$query="SELECT * FROM `members` where `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'";

// added an or die clause to check for SQL errors
$result=mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

// use of mysql_fetch_assoc to put user data into associative array
$user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
mysql_close();
?> <br /> <p></p>

Welcome back! Your details below: <br /><br /> 

<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5"> 
<tr> 
 <th>First Name</th> 
 <th>Last Name</th>
 <th>User Name</th>
 <th>Email</th> 
 <th>Age</th> 
</tr>

<?php
// removed unnecessary loop as i'd assume the username will only be in the database once
$firstname= $user['firstname']; 
$lastname= $user['lastname']; 
$username= $user['username']; 
$email= $user['email']; 
$age= $user['age']; 
?>

 <tr> 
   <td><? echo $firstname ?></td> 
   <td><? echo $lastname ?></td>
   <td><? echo $username ?></td>
   <td><? echo $email ?></td>
   <td><? echo $age ?></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct.

```
phpcs test.php 

FILE: /tmp/test.php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 4 ERROR(S) AND 1 WARNING(S) AFFECTING 4 LINE(S)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2 | ERROR   | Missing file doc comment
  3 | ERROR   | "include" is a statement, not a function; no parentheses are
    |         | required
  3 | ERROR   | File is being unconditionally included; use "require" instead
 25 | ERROR   | Short PHP opening tag used. Found "<?" Expected "<?php".
 29 | WARNING | Inline control structures are discouraged
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Actually none of these are fatal errors, i.e. the php runtime could still execute the script. Those are "only" guidelines or policies. Good ones maybe. But still they need explaining.

Comment: We don't know what kind of check is being asked for. So I assumed I was free to choose the check I was going to do, and what would be considered an error. This answer is not really serious, it's rather a joke to get more precisions from the asker. And these checks are valuable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
$username=$_POST['username']; $email=$_POST['email'];

$query="SELECT * FROM members where username = '$username'";
```

Search stackoverflow for "sql injections" and maybe also for "prepared statements".

```
<td><? echo $firstname ?></td>
```

The same way your sql statement is prone to sql injections this line might be the cause for injections into your html code. Use `<td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($firstname); ?></td>` instead.

---

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
```

Why is that in there? You don't use $email again until `$email=mysql_result($result, $i, 'email');`. My guess is your original query tested for both the username and the email address?

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < $num) {
   mysql_result($result, $i,
   i++
   ...
```

How many members with the same username can there be in your database table? More than one? If not, why do you use the while loop?

```
$firstname=mysql_result($result, $i, 'firstname'); 
$lastname=mysql_result($result, $i, 'lastname'); 
$username=mysql_result($result, $i, 'username'); 
$email=mysql_result($result, $i, 'email'); 
$age= mysql_result($result, $i, 'age');
```

Instead of five calls to `mysql_result()` one call to [mysql_fetch_array()](http://docs.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) would suffice. Speed is probably not an issue here but again it adds a tiny bit of complexity that seems unnecessary to me and when you use mysql_fetch_xyz() you only have one variable (an array or an object) to worry about instead of *#columns* variables

Comment: hmm.. ok ok . i see. its my fault. i forgot to edit it. haha. anyway, thanks! this is a big help. ;)